# What is the point of using constants in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jscript

What is the meaning of using a constant in JavaScript?
`var` and `const` do almost the same thing but `const` is unchangable.
What is the point of that and what situation would use `const`?

Comment: `const` is not supported across many browsers. I believe only Firefox supports it fully, with Safari and Opera only giving partial support.

Comment: `const` is a future reserved word, it is not part of ECMAScript, though it is in JavaScript™.

Comment: @Dominic Barnes, partial support of a syntactic feature? That's interesting. Which part of the keyword, exactly, do they support?

Comment: OK, it seems in Opera you can use `const`, but these constants can be dereferenced (overwritten). In Chromium and Safari `const` works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing the advantage is that you'll be sure your constant's value doesn't change, ever.

Which might also help the Javascript engine optimize things a bit, depending on its implementation.

Note though that, according to [this page (const in MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) :

> `const` is a Mozilla-specific extension, it is not supported by IE, but
>   has been partially supported by Opera since version 9.0 and Safari.

So, using `const` is probably not that much of a good idea.